# Best Practice For Excluding Large Test Files From Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've developed a rails plugin/gem that has some fairly large files for testing (images, videos, etc). What is the best practice for ensuring they aren't pushed up/downloaded from rubygems while still keeping them in the repository? Is it required to be able to run the tests for a gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) for building your gems you can use `include` or `exclude` to set pattern on what should or shouldn't be in your gem. Something like...

```
gem.files.exclude 'tmp' # exclude temporary directory
gem.files.include 'lib/foo/bar.rb' # explicitly include lib/foo/bar.rb
```

[Check documentation](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler#files) for more information.